# Javascript NaN bug

Tags: javascript, html, nan

Here is my js function. When I enter the data i get NaN

```
//BMI is defined as BMI = ( Weight in Pounds / ( Height in inches x Height in inches ) ) x 703
function calculatebmi(weight, height){
    //window.alert("hello");
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("weight_pounds"));
    var height = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("height_inches"));

    var bmi = parseInt(((weight/height)*703));
    window.alert("your BMI is: " + bmi);
}
```

I have tried math.floor and innerHTML. Both didn't help.

The input tag type is number, in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: Your BMI formula is wrong. You need to take the square of height.

Comment: Wow. A unique combination of two basic errors, the first being not to realize that `getElementsbyName` yields a nodelist you have to take the first element of (why are you using names instead of IDs anyway?), and the second not remembering to take the value of an element using its `value` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns `NodeList`

You need to use `[0]` notation to get first element from this collection and then use `value` property.

```
var value = document.getElementsByName('weight_pounds')[0].value;
var weight = parseInt(value, 10);
```

For `parseInt` function `radix`(second parameter) by default  is `10`, but you need to specify it.
From MDN:

> Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the value inside of `parseInt` instead of a node object,

```
 var weight = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("weight_pounds")[0].value);
```

If you pass an object into `parseInt` rather than a numeric string, it will return `NaN`. Also it is advised to use the `radix` parameter of `parseInt` as `10`, but nowadays recent browser will consider radix as 10 by default.

Note that, `getElementsByName` will return a html collection, so you cannot access the value of required element directly. You have to get its first element by using bracket notation `[0]` and access its value. So to avoid such problems you can use `.querySelector()` like below,

```
 var weight = parseInt(document.querySelector("input[name='weight_pounds'])").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse the nodes themselves, when you should be trying to parse their values (with `.value`), and you don't index the collection returned by `getElementsByName`:

```
var weight = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("weight_pounds")[0].value);
var height = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("height_inches")[0].value);
```